Timeout in ansible when executing flux bootstrap
I am using Hyperledger Bevel to manage a Hyperledger Fabric 2.2 network. It has been working ok so far but I am not trying to perform some maintenance actions executing the playbook:
ansible-playbook platforms/shared/configuration/site.yaml -e "@./build/network-iprd-qa.yaml"

This used to work but now I am getting a timeout when the flux bootstrap command tries to clone the git repository:

Failed to clone repository: context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout or context cancellation while reading body)

in the flux bootstrap step when executing Ansible. Looks like Bevel repository takes a long time to clone.
How can I extend the timeout for that action in the network.yaml file? (Or through a context value). Thanks.

Set a higher timeout for your flux command according to the documentation.
flux bootstrap --timeout duration        timeout for this operation (default 5m0s)


Probably it's because I don't know much abut Flux or Ansible but... Can that be done thorugh a environment variable? It turns out that the script executing flux is in Ansible, in a GitOps script, so I'd rather not edit those files if I can alter those parameters using environment variables.

No, as far as i know. I think you have to change the ansible playbook, but this should be a no-brainer.
